# count function is showing by default value as 1

Tags: php, file, count, drupal-7

I am using count function of php to count the how many files are chosen while file uploading the files. Depend upon the count I want to apply some conditions. When no files chosen, then I checked the count value, its showing as 1, and when I chose a single file it shows 1, after selecting two files it will show count as 2. I am not getting whats going wrong here. Please find the below code,  I have written. Thanks for any suggsetions..

```
  $form['upload_fieldset']['file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => 'Choose a File',
    '#name' => 'files[]',
    '#attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple'),

  );
function xxx_submit_file_upload($form, &$form_state) { 
  $num_files = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

echo '<pre>';print_r($num_files);exit;//Here I am getting count as 1. if no files were chosen also.
```

Comment: try `count($_FILES['files'])` or just `count($_FILES)` or `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: did u test it? ? ?

Comment: Just now I tested count($_FILES['file‌​s']) this will give correct result. May i know What is the problem with my code?

Comment: `$_FILES['files']` consist on complete array, and `$_FILES['files']['name']` will return only one or nothing. u can test `var_dump($_FILES['files']['name'])'

Comment: Actually  count($_FILES['file‌​s']) this is giving always 0, if file chosen also zero its showing,and count($_FILES) this is giving always 1.

Comment: you must need to check `print_r($_FILES)`

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't have a file, `$_FILES['files']['name']` is set to `''` so it does count as 1.

You can check if a file is uploaded or not and then count :

```
$upload_error = $_FILES['files']['error'][0];

if ($upload_error === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    $num_files = 0;
} else {
    $num_files = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working for me. You can try it.

```
    $num_files = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $name) {
    if (!empty($name))
        $num_files++;
}

if( $num_files == 0 ){
    echo "No file selected";
}else{
    echo $num_files." files uploaded.";
}
```